# Error Number: 1064, ExpressionEngine 1.7.3 Chrome Bug

Tags: error, ee1, debugging

I am getting the following error in Chrome for my site:

MySQL ERROR:

Error Number: 1064

Description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'd code on line 341'' at line 1

Query: SELECT cat_name FROM exp_categories WHERE cat_id ='Notice: Undefined variable: catID in /www/eh17535/public_html/cp/core/core.functions.php(672) : eval()'d code on line 341'

I am only getting this in Chrome, IE and firefox work fine.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Allison

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a server-side error (like the MySQL error you describe) cannot be happening in one browser but not another. So my guess is that you're simply viewing the specific page on which it is happening with Chrome, and viewing a *different* page in Firefox and IE.

(Or, another possibility - you're logged-in in Chrome, but not the others, and the error is triggered by code that is only running for logged-in users.)

My guess - you have a custom add-on or PHP in a specific template that's running a query which triggers the error. Search your templates for `$catID` to find the culprit.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I was logged in, which showed the variable it didn't recognize. Once I logged out, the error was gone. Thanks!